# Awk - split html file from comments

Tags: linux, bash, split, awk, grep

I have an html file with comments like this (some can be nested)

```
<!-- Begin foo.html -->
<p>some html code</p>

    <!-- Begin foo2.html -->
    <p>some html code</p>
    <!-- End foo2.html -->

<!-- End foo.html -->

<!-- Begin bar.html -->
<p>some html code</p>
<!-- End bar.html -->
```

What I m trying to do is split the html file into foo.html, foo2.html and bar.html.
The number of block comment is not known. as the name of the block.
So far i have this awk line

```
awk '/<!-- Begin (.*?)-->/ {f=$1} f{print > f}  /<!-- End \1 -->/{close f; f=""}' index.html
```

But it doesn't work properly.

Any thoughts on how to fix this, or any alternate method that would help?

Comment: and whas is supposed to happen to foo2.html?  And why are you using awk to do this?

Comment: Sorry, foo2.html must be split too. I actually thought awk could do the job.

Comment: So you mean foo2.html needs to be split in a separate foo2.html file? You need to update your question to add this detail.

Comment: I'm sure you can do it with awk but it's probably not ideal tool for this job.  Consider using one of the more versatile scripting languages which are pretty much as ubiquitous as awk (Python, Perl).

Answer (score 1):

Though I am not quite clear with the question. But if you have specific comments, then you can give a regex range. foo2.html portion will also get appended in foo.html. Something like this -

```
awk '
/Begin foo.html/,/End foo.html/{print $0 > "foo.html"}
/Begin bar.html/,/End bar.html/{print $0 > "bar.html"}' index.html
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat index.html 
<!-- Begin foo.html -->
<p>some html code</p>

    <!-- Begin foo2.html -->
    <p>some html code</p>
    <!-- End foo2.html -->

<!-- End foo.html -->

<!-- Begin bar.html -->
<p>some html code</p>
<!-- End bar.html -->

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '/Begin foo.html/,/End foo.html/{print $0 > "foo.html"}
/Begin bar.html/,/End bar.html/{print $0 > "bar.html"}' index.html

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat foo.html 
<!-- Begin foo.html -->
<p>some html code</p>

    <!-- Begin foo2.html -->
    <p>some html code</p>
    <!-- End foo2.html -->

<!-- End foo.html -->

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat bar.html 
<!-- Begin bar.html -->
<p>some html code</p>
<!-- End bar.html -->
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my case, I don't know foo.html or foo2.html, thats why i used /<!-- Begin (.*?)-->/

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat input.txt
<!-- Begin foo.html -->
<p>some html code</p>

    <!-- Begin foo2.html -->
    <p>some html code</p>
    <!-- End foo2.html -->

<!-- End foo.html -->

<!-- Begin bar.html -->
<p>some html code</p>
<!-- End bar.html -->

$ awk '/<!-- Begin/{stack[sp++]=$3; print ">>>", $3; next}; /<!-- End/{sp--; print "<<<", $3; next}; {if(sp>0) print > stack[sp-1]}' input.txt
>>> foo.html
>>> foo2.html
<<< foo2.html
<<< foo.html
>>> bar.html
<<< bar.html

$ for i in {foo,foo2,bar}.html; do echo "=====$i======"; cat $i; done
=====foo.html======
<p>some html code</p>


=====foo2.html======
    <p>some html code</p>
=====bar.html======
<p>some html code</p>
```

I've added `debug msg`. After removing `print ">>>", $3`, code is much short.

```
$ awk '/<!-- Begin/{stack[sp++]=$3; next}; /<!-- End/{sp--; next}; {if(sp>0) print > stack[sp-1]}' input.txt
```

At last, you should reformat the html(indent is not correct)!

Comment: I think this is the best possible answer to what OP wants.